# select one view to display between 2 views in android?

Tags: android, view

i have two view

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/lighter_gray"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        />
```

I want to select only one view to shown at run time , is there container for them to do the job ? 
i searched and found something like viewswitcher ,but i dont want to switch between them i only want to display one of them

Comment: you can manage visibility bases on one button at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set video view and image view visibility to gone in xml by adding `android:visibility="gone"`

and setVisibility to visible in java code based on the requirement or which view you want to show.

Comment: yeah that works fine ,but i have a list with hundred of items, i want to release the view

Comment: Don't process or initialise the view with data which is not visible